# norms on matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let ||.|| be a norm on matrices and let $A$ and $B$ be matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. I need to show that if $||I-AB||<1$, then $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

Sorry if the question is not clear. I translated it from another language.

Comment: I think you might want to say that $A$ and $B$ are *invertible*, not that they are *inevitable*.  It does appear, however, *inevitable* that $A$ and $B$ are *invertible*.

Comment: I edited you post a tiny little bit.  Cheers!

Comment: As stated, this is false, for if $M \mapsto q(M)$ is a norm, then so is $M \mapsto c\cdot q(M)$ for any positive $c$. Perhaps what was intended was that $\| \cdot \|$ was the standard 2-norm on matrices?

Comment: It is common to use "matrix norm" to refer implicitly to a *submultiplicative* matrix norm.

Comment: That's certainly another possible intent here --- good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $\|\cdot\|$ is meant to refer to a (submultiplicative) matrix norm.

First, show that $\|I - M\| < 1$ implies that $M$ is invertible.  Do this either by considering the eigenvalues of $M$, or by considering the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty M^k$.

Next, use the fact that if $AB$ is invertible, then it follows that both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.  To that end, it suffices to consider the determinant $\det(AB)= \det(A) \det(B)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have trouble in proving the first part :( would you please help me more? :(

Comment: Note that since $\|I - M\| < 1$, all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $I-M$ satisfy $|\lambda| < 1$.  Perhaps you could take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is false; for example, consider the max norm, with $A=I$ and $B$ the matrix with all entries equal to $1/2$. Then
$$\|I-AB\|_{\mathrm{max}} = \frac{1}{2} < 1$$
but $B$ is not invertible (for $n>1$).